# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(). For converting predictions into text

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, nltk

I am working on a language translation model and while executing a particular code cell, I get a value error. The code is mentioned below.

```
preds_text = []
for i in preds:
    temp = []
    for j in range(len(i)):
      t = get_word((i[j]), eng_tokenizer)
      if j>0:
        if (t == get_word(i[j-1], eng_tokenizer)) or (t == None):
          temp.append('')
        else:
          temp.append(t)
      else:
        if(t == None):
          temp.append('')
        else:
          temp.append(t)
    preds_text.append(''.join(temp))
```

This particular line causes the error

```
t = get_word((i[j]), eng_tokenizer)
```

This is the error I got after running it

**ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()**

Can anyone please help me out in this regard?

Comment: You will need to investigate the `get_word` function. The error stacktrace may provide more information. Also check that you're passing the expected inputs to `get_word`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply to my query. Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: Can you please provide the full error message? Also, can you please include a link or reference about the `get_word` function?